# Displaying only specific index when iterating tuple of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, tuples

I want to display 2nd value in tuple of tuples.What are the multiple ways to make sure this happens?

```py
tuple =((1,"qwerty","poiuyt"),(2,"mnbvc","waxds"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tuple unpacking is always clean:

```
>>> t =((1,"qwerty","poiuyt"),(2,"mnbvc","waxds"))
>>> tuple(y for x, y, z in t)
('qwerty', 'mnbvc')
```

You can use indexing as well:

```
>>> tuple(x[1] for x in t)
('qwerty', 'mnbvc')
```

Using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> tuple(map(itemgetter(1), t))
('qwerty', 'mnbvc')
```

Using `lambda`:

```
>>> tuple(map(lambda x: x[1], t))
('qwerty', 'mnbvc')
```

Plus many more other variations.